# Focus an IntraWeb IWTreeView on a selected item

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, intraweb, intraweb-10

I have a rather lengthy tree view (IWTreeView) in a IWRegion (ClipRegion:= True) with one 
node selected. How do I focus that node such that it is visible for the user 
after a render? The

What I do so far:

In Delphi

```
tree.Selected:= itemToFocus;
tree.ScrollToName:= tree.Selected.Name;
```

This generates this on my website (done by IWTreeView.pas by Atozed):

```
<script language="javascript">
  ...
  function initialize {
    ...
    positionNAVIGATORTree( "i2" );
  }
</script>
...
<script language="javascript">
  function positionNAVIGATORTree( iNodeID )
  {
    FindElem( "NAVIGATOR").scrollTop =
      FindElem( iNodeID ).offsetTop - 40;
     return true;
  }
</script>
```

Still the tree after a render will show the topmost item. This is true for all browsers I have tested (IE8, Firefox, Chrome).

Comment: There is an error in FindElement by AToZed, which will be fixed in a future version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript function `window.scrollTo(x,y)` allows you to scroll a window, will that work for your control?

Answer (score 0):

Elite Suite (recently open-sourced) has much better treeview (TArcIWStringGrid+TArcIWStringGridTreeContent) with perfectly working selection and scrolling. Try it!